# Problem with non-power steering

Tags: toyota, steering, echo

I have a car without power steering. Recently, when turning the steering wheel, it seems to "catch" in places making it extra hard for me to turn it. (Not sure if this is related, but the problem started after the car sat for a couple of weeks.) Any suggestions as to what might be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please tell us what year/make/model of car you are asking about.

Comment: See [Have I provided enough information regarding my problem?](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1474/675)

Comment: It's a 2004 Toyota Echo.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the way rack and pinion steering works, more than likely you have a broken or cracked tooth in the steering rack. It doesn't matter if it's power or non, this can happen. A sharp jounce through a pothole might cause this. Hitting a curb at just the right speed and direction can do it as well. More than likely you're facing replacement of your unit.

Here is a very basic image depiction of a R&P unit:

[image]

A broken or cracked tooth on either the rack or the pinion could cause what you're talking about. When the unit gets to the tooth, it seems to get "stuck" there until you force it past. Most of the time, teeth to the either side of the damaged tooth will start to fail and the "catch" will get bigger and harder to get past.

Comment: Couldn't worn out strut bearings cause the same feeling? Those are much more common to fail than damage to the steering rack.

Comment: @MadMarky - what on earth is a strut bearing?  That's not a real thing.  Also the fact that it's doing it in certain places in a turn almost confirms it's the rack.  I had one that would seize only on left turns.  It would build up so much pressure from the pump it was blowing fluid past the seals.

Comment: @JohnLord a bearing on top of the front strut, allowing the whole assembly to rotate with ease. When they go bad there will be grinding and eventually some difficulty in steering. Also see [this page](https://www.cars.com/auto-repair/glossary/strut-bearing/)

Comment: i've seen bushing up there.  Must be something specific to certain models.  According to that page some cars don't have them at all and some have them built into the strut.